# How to change theme of the entire app using 3 different themes (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, themes

In this app there are three different themes - Red, Black and White. From the main screen the user can navigate to a theme screen where they will be given the choice to select a particular theme. I wanted to use an approach which would use a function or a constructor from a class returning a `ThemeData` and sends it to `theme:` of the `MaterialApp` in `main.dart`.

Is this a valid approach? if yes then could i get a guide on how to properly set the theme on `MaterialApp`. 
if no, Could i get some suggestion on how i could set the three themes in this app.

this is the class which i am trying to pass as a constructor and set the particular background theme color :

```
class ThemeChooser extends StatelessWidget {
  static int color;
  ThemeData data = ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(color));
  ThemeChooser({color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeChooser(color: color,);
  }
}
```

this is the button which chooses the theme (this is only one button but assume there are two more for setting black and white themes) :

```
    FlatButton(
               onPressed: ()async {
               final result = await Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute( 
                 builder: (context) => ThemeScreen(),                              
                             ));
                          setState(() {
                            setThemeRed(redcolor);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 8),
                          child: whitefontstyle(text: "Red", size: 50,),
                        )
                    ),
```

this is the method which uses the constructor from `ThemeChooser` to set the theme (i have only delared the setting to red theme atm.) :

```
int color;

setThemeRed(int color){
  return ThemeChooser(color: redcolor,);
}
```

this is the main method:

```
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
// the theme below also needs to take the value in ThemeChooser set in ThemeScreen.

//    theme: 
    home: TodoList(),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebuild the material app every time you change the theme. So you can use BLoC to do that.

```
class ThemeBloc{
   final _themeController = StreamController<ThemeData>.broadcast();
   Sink<ThemeData> get inputter => _themeController.sink;
   Stream<ThemeData> get outputter => _themeController.stream;

  ThemeBloc(){
  // when the app loads put the initial themeData that 
  //you want to show
   inputter.add(initialThemeData); 
   }

   //use this to dispose the controller whenever the app gets closed
   void dispose(){
      _themeController.close();
   }

}
```

Now use StreamBuilder to wrap the MaterialApp,

```
  ThemeBloc _bloc = ThemeBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
      stream: bloc.outputter,
      initialData: defaultThemeData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => MaterialApp(
            home: ToDoList(),
            theme: snapshot.data,// this is the themeData that we're getting from the 
                                 //stream
          ),
    );
  }
```

Now how can we change the theme?

```
  //let's say we have a button that would change the theme,
  RaisedButton(){
    onPressed: (){
    inputter.add(redTheme); // redTheme is a ThemeData that you must give,
    },
    child: Text("Enable Red Theme")
  }
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work!

Comment: Will this method change the theme from the 'theme' screen without collapsing all the way back to the home screen when the theme is changed on the theme screen?

Comment: It will change the app's whole theme. But now there are a lot of libraries available in pub.dev for changing themes easily. You can use those instead.